# SQL exception was unhandled by user code on connection open

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, entity-framework

i am beginner to microsoft asp.net and i got An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code error when trying to select value from Microsoft visual studio database. The error was on the con.Open() line

Below is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\Ng\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Assignment6\Assignment6\App_Data\photoCompetition.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM User WHERE email=@username and password=@word", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", emailtext.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", passwordtext.Text);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMsg.Text = "Your username and word is incorrect";
                    lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why is there a space in `C: \Users\Ng\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Assignment6\Assignment6\App_Data\photoCompetition.mdf`? Try to remove it first. Also use the `using` keyword on your `SqlConnection` to properly dispose it.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the code inside `try...catch` block and check what is the problem?

Comment: i had remove the space but now the error is at the sda.Fill(dt) line...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So your first issue is that you had a space in your Sql Connection string.

`C: \Users\Ng\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Assignment6\Assignment6\App_Data\photoCompetit‌​ion.mdf`

Now since your query looks valid and assuming the tables and columns exists, you are having a problem with the SQL query you are trying to execute. I see two options here.

1. Enclose your parameters with a single quote to denote it as a string

   ```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM User WHERE email='@username' and password='@word'", con);
   ```
2. Use [SqlParameterCollection.Add Method (String, SqlDbType, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x(v=vs.110).aspx).

   ```
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.Text).Value = emailtext.Text;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@word", SqlDbType.Text).Value = passwordtext.Text;
   ```

Also, don't forget to close your `SqlConnection` with `con.Close();`

Comment: i have modify my code but that sda.fill line still got error with message Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

Comment: The command should be setup as follows: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE email=@username and password=@word", con);` There is no need for the quotes.

Comment: @mjwills you obviously didn't get what I said. Best of luck.

Comment: Can you point out which part that I misunderstood? I've never seen quotes put around parameters like that (since they aren't needed). Can you point us to somewhere else you have seen that technique used? Also, you need [ and ] around User since it is a SQL Server reserved word - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql .